# Adding Hibernate to the Spring project using IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: mysql, spring, hibernate, intellij-idea

I am trying to add Hibernate to my project.

I clicked on view -> Tool windows -> databes and added new MySQL database. I tested connection it was ok.

Then i clicked on view -> Tool windows -> persistence.

Persistence window appeared. I right clicked -> Generate Persistence Mapping -> By database schema. I chosed the database i added , selected package and generated hibernate.cgf.xml and mapped entity.

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
    "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD//EN"
    "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
  <session-factory>
    <property name="connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mydb</property>
    <property name="connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
      <mapping class="db.mydbEntity"/>
      <!-- DB schema will be updated if needed -->
    <!-- <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">update</property> -->
  </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

Yet it cannot throws error

"Cannot resolve class Driver".

I downloaded sql connector from [here](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/j/). Clicked on File -> Project structure -> Libraries -> clicked on green plus , selected java and added file i downloaded to it.

yet the error remains the same , how can i fix this? I cannot find any tutorial or this nor some solution.

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you extract the driver from the archive you downloaded? The file you want to add to the libraries section in Intellij is `mysql-connector-java-5.1.41-bin.jar`

Answer (score 0):

you will need to add the mysql API, its seem like you didnt add it with your libraries